# Do homogeneous ideals have homogeneous primary decomposition?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

In proving closed algebraic set in $\mathbb P_n(k)$ has decomposition into irreducible algebraic sets, we can argue by decomposition in noetherian space.

> Can we prove directly by decomposition of homogeneous ideal into homogeneous prime ideals?

I don't know if this holds. I tried to use the correspondence between ideals in $k[X_1,...,X_n]$ and homogeneous ideals in $k[X_0,...,X_n]$ by $I \rightarrow {}^hI$ and ${}^aJ \leftarrow J$. Suppose we have $J$ a homogeneous ideal in $k[X_0,...,X_n]$, then ${}^aJ = \mathfrak{q}_1\cap\cdots\cap\mathfrak{q}_k$
and we have ${}^h({}^aJ) = {}^h\mathfrak{q}_1\cap\cdots\cap{}^h\mathfrak{q}_k$ a primary decomposition. But ${}^h({}^aJ)=J$ may not hold. Take $J=(X_0,...,X_n)$ for example: ${}^h({}^aJ)=k[X_0,..,X_n]$

I saw tags here: "[minimal primes of a homogeneous ideal are homogeneous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32595/minimal-primes-of-a-homogeneous-ideal-are-homogeneous)" but the problem was not fully answered and the cited link is missing.

Can anyone answer that tag or help me with this question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's true that the homogeneous ideals have homogeneous primary decompositions in any finitely generated graded algebra over a field. This follows from the usual primary decomposition by taking the homogeneous parts of primary ideals involved into decomposition. (For more details see [here](http://www.imsc.res.in/~kapil/geometry/caag/proj.html), Section 1.4.)

For the part of your question about the minimal primes of homogeneous ideals look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/176068/are-minimal-prime-ideals-in-a-graded-ring-graded/176084#176084).

Comment: May I ask another question? Is there any way to tell when do ${}^h{}^aJ$ and $J$ coincide? Thanks!

Comment: @mqx Maybe you should post this as a separate question. The algebraic geometers can answer you better than me.