# Question about irreducible components of affine varieties defined by homogeneous polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have $F_1, \ldots, F_r \in \mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ homogeneous polynomials. Consider their zero set $V(F_1, ..., F_r)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ and let $Z_1, ..., Z_t$ be the irreducible components. How do I know that each $Z_i$ contains $(0,...,0)$? Thank you very much!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/524396/do-homogeneous-ideals-have-homogeneous-primary-decomposition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Z$ be an irreducible component and let $p=(a_1,\ldots, a_n)$ be a point on $Z$ not in any other component. If it is the origin, you have nothing to show. For any $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$, $(\lambda a_1,\ldots, \lambda a_n)$ belongs to $V(F_i)$, since these are homogeneous. That is, you have a morphism $\mathbb{C}\to V(F_i)$ and since the former is irreducible, the image is contained in an irreducible component and now it is clear the image is contained in $Z$ and thus the origin belongs to $Z$.

Comment: Are you considering only one $V(F_i)$ or are you doing this for all of them?

Comment: All of them, I meant $V(F_1,\ldots,F_r)$.

Answer (score 1):

Homogenous ideals have a homogenous primary decomposition, see [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=iwIysWcq2HIC&pg=PA103&lpg=PA103&dq=primary%20decomposition%20of%20homogeneous%20ideals&source=bl&ots=fc7joYDWG8&sig=me4bOUVJ7gm-cJVSOIcK_yJTj_8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2l5z98YjTAhXKtxQKHcZhB90Q6AEIUzAF#v=onepage&q=primary%20decomposition%20of%20homogeneous%20ideals&f=false) (Theorem 10). Your desired statement is just the geometric version of this.